# Page has too many requests

Tags: php, html, mysql

having an issue with page chrome saying there are too many redirects, the page, finally does what i want(at least does function correctly as far as i know, as i tested it with a close connection, sticking at the top of page, and it is displaying the userID. When logged in this page does the redirecting, im not too sure how to fix this, found lots of different posts online, and each one was so different from the next.

```
<?php session_start();
include'../../connection.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".../../../../style.css">
    <title>Home</title>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<?php include('../../main/main.php');?>
</head>
  <body>



<div class=containermain>
  <h1>I5-6600k.php</h1>
<form action="ratepost.php" method="post">

<label for="rating">rating:</label>
<select name="rating" id="rating" value="rating" >
<option>
    <option value="1">1 </option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3 </option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



  <h2>graphics card write up................</h2>
  <?php echo "Hello " . $_SESSION['user']; ?>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>

<div
  class="fb-like"
  data-share="true"
  data-width="450"
  data-show-faces="true">
</div>

<!---------------------------------------COMMENT BOX---------------------------------------------------->

<div class="comments" align="center">
<form action="" method="post" >
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment">
Please type a comment if you are logged in....


</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>


<?php

if (isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id'])) {
 $id = $_SESSION['login_id'];
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO comment (userID, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('$id', '$comment', '1')";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert)){


      header("Location: i5-6600k");

} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sqlinsert. " . mysqli_error($conn);

}

}

    // close connection











$sql  = "SELECT `users`.`username`, `comment`.`comment`, `comment`.`timestamp`\n"

    . "FROM `users`\n"

    . "LEFT JOIN `comment` ON `users`.`userID` = `comment`.`userID` \n"

    . "where dCpuID = 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>Username</th><th>Comment</th><th>Timestamp</th>";
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["comment"]."</td><td>"  . $row["timestamp"]. "</td>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}


?>  
</div>
<?php include('../../assets/footer.php');?>

<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.computercomparison.tk/#home" data-numposts="5"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all, you should have the `header()` redirect above browser output accompanied by `exit;`, second, if you don't `unset()` on the session `$_SESSION['login_id']` it's going to keep redirecting and probably reinserting into your database. As long as that is set, this will be satisfied `if (isset($_SESSION['login_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['login_id'])) {` and keep redirecting (assuming this page is called `i5-6600k`)

Comment: What is this `i5-6600k` in the header?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer will implement changes in a little while. The i5, is the CPU model, building a site with lots of different models on it, WIP at the moment not too far into it as yet...

Comment: The problem is if i unset, it logs out the user, if i don't it spams the db

Comment: ill try remove header see what happens

Comment: What are you trying to do with that part?

Comment: Basically, the header was just to redirect to page after comment insert. The point is the logged in user can comment on the page, it is in a table structure as follows. username, userid, etc comment, comment id, comment, userid

Comment: the issue earlier on was username was being entered into the userid box(fixed earlier that issue at lease) but fixing that issue created the redirect one, and also the comment box either gets spammed with userid, or a comment doesn't get entered full stop, one extreme or the other unfortunately :/

Comment: Ok, I'll write you an answer for some things to try. Give me a few...

Comment: No problem, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what you are doing here, you are missing how to effectively process an action. You are triggering your comment by checking if something, which is persistent, exists and acting on it. If it's a session variable, it will persist, therefore the action is infinite until it stops persisting. You need an action in your submission.

I would have a config page that you include with all pages that contains re-usable variables. It would be stored in the root of the site. In general, you have some HTML errors and some unsafe SQL injection issues. I have created a little more complicated version of your page (without the bottom half, that needs a lot of work and should be wrapped as well) but it's only complicated to make the view less complicated...if that makes sense. Anyway, if you have issues let me know, I haven't tested this.

**/config.php**

```
<?php
# Create some absolute defines for consistent includes
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT_DIR',__DIR__);
define('VENDOR',ROOT_DIR.DS.'vendor');
define('SITE_URL','http://www.example.com');

# Start session
session_start();
# Autoloads all the classes we intend to use
spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $path = VENDOR.DS.trim(str_replace('\\',DS,$class),DS).'.php';
    if(is_file($path))
        require_once($path);
});
```

**/vendor/App.php**

```
<?php
# General/base class used for various time-saving actions
class App
    {
        # Store this object for re-use
        protected   static $singleton;
        # Store others (if using getHelper() method)
        protected   static $apps;
        # Create singleton
        public function __construct()
            {
                if(!(self::$singleton instanceof \App))
                    self::$singleton = $this;
                # Return back the same object
                return self::$singleton;
            }
        # Get either the full post or just one key/value
        public function getPost($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_POST[$key]))? $_POST[$key] : false;

                return $_POST;
            }
        # Get session or just one key/value pair
        public function getSession($key=false)
            {
                if(!empty($key))
                    return (isset($_SESSION[$key]))? $_SESSION[$key] : false;
                return $_SESSION;
            }

        # Write and destroy session value
        public function writeError($key)
            {
                $error = $this->getSession($key);
                $this->destroy($key);
                return $error;
            }

        public function destroy($key = false)
            {
                if(!empty($key)) {
                    if(isset($_SESSION[$key]))
                        $_SESSION[$key] = NULL;

                    return;
                }

                session_destroy();
            }
        # Sets a session value
        public function setSession($key,$value)
            {
                $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
            }
        # Consistent way to write the site url (set in the config)
        public function siteUrl($path = false,$ssl=false)
            {
                return ($ssl)? str_replace('http://','https://',SITE_URL).$path : SITE_URL.$path;
            }
        # Creates an instance if this object
        public static function call()
            {
                return new \App();
            }
        # Saves and uses classes
        public function getHelper($class,$inject=NULL)
            {
                $setKey = str_replace('\\','',$class);

                if(isset(self::$apps[$setKey]))
                    return self::$apps[$setKey];

                self::$apps[$setKey] = new $class($inject);

                return self::$apps[$setKey];
            }
    }
```

**/vendor/Router/Model.php**

```
<?php
# Use for redirects, can be expanded out to do other router-type things
namespace Router;

class Model extends \App
    {
        public function addRedirect($path)
            {
                header('Location: '.$path);
                exit;
            }
    }
```

**/vendor/View/Model.php**

```
<?php
# This is a wrapper for the page
namespace View;

class Model extends \App
    {
        public function render($path)
            {
                if(!is_file($path))
                    return;
                # Create a buffer and render contents
                ob_start();
                include($path);
                $data = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                return $data;
            }
    }
```

**/vendor/Commenter/Model.php**

```
<?php
namespace Commenter;

class Observer extends \Router\Model
    {
        # Listen for action name, do action when required
        public function listen($conn)
            {
                if($this->getPost('action') != 'addcomment')
                    return false;

                if(!empty($this->getSession('login_id'))) {
                    $id = $this->getSession('login_id');
                    # You will want to bind parameters on this. This is an opening for SQL Injection (Google it)
                    $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO comment (userID, comment, dCpuID) VALUES ('$id', '".$this->getPost('comment')."', '1')";

                    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sqlinsert))
                        $this->addRedirect("i5-6600k");
                    else
                        $this->setSession('error',"ERROR: Could not able to execute $sqlinsert. " . mysqli_error($conn));
                }
            }
    }
```

**whatever this page is called...**

```
<?php
# Create separator
$DS = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
# Include config file
include(realpath(__DIR__.$DS.'..'.$DS.'..').$DS.'config.php');
# Check to see if this file is being wrapped by render class
if(!isset($this)) {
    # Include this file into the renderer
    echo \App::call()->getHelper('\View\Model')->render(__FILE__);
    exit;
}
# Include connection
include(ROOT_DIR.DS.'connection.php');
# Listen for the add comment action
$this->getHelper('\Commenter\Observer')->listen($conn);
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->siteUrl('/style.css') ?>">
    <title>Home</title>

    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<?php include(ROOT_DIR.DS.'main'.DS.'main.php');?>
</head>
<body>
<div class="containermain" style="padding-bottom: 60px;">
    <h1>I5-6600k.php</h1>
    <form action="ratepost.php" method="post">
        <label for="rating">rating:</label>
        <select name="rating" id="rating" value="rating">
            <?php for($i=1; $i<=5;$i++) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <h2>graphics card write up................</h2>
    Hello <?php echo $this->getSession('user') ?>
</div>
<div class="fb-like" data-share="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

<!--- COMMENT BOX --->

<div class="comments" align="center">
    <?php echo $this->writeError('error') ?>
    <form action="" method="post" >
        <!-- YOU NEED TO SEND AN ACTION WORD HERE AND CHECK FOR IT
             TO PROCESS POST -->
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addcomment" />
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="comment">Please type a comment if you are logged in...</textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

...etc.
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do all of that. Appreciated. However there was a minor syntax issue in the vendor file, have changed them, however pages are not loading at all. The syntax was only swapping ; for { on 1 line on them

Comment: all the vendor/model ones, not the others

Comment: Sorry, yes you are right, I stupidly put a `;` after I declared the classes. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of the main page *(last piece of code in my example)*. That will tell the error(s). I had a couple other syntax errors that I fixed and tested out and It should all work now if you have things in the right spots.